# JSON parsing with GSON Structure

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I've tried to do this in another project, and as per the tutorials I've seen, I know I am on the right track, but I cannot get this parsing correctly:

(Much Simplified) JSON Output:

```
{
"data":{
  "info":{
      "username": "something"
      "email" : "something"
   }
..
..
```

}

I am trying to get "username" and "email using the following classes:

```
class ProfileResponse {
static Data data;

public static Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public static void setData(Data data) {
    ProfileResponse.data = data;
}
```

}

```
Class Data {
@SerializedName("info")
static Info info;

public static Info getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public static void setInfo(Info info) {
    Data.info = info;
}
```

}

```
class Info {
@SerializedName("username")
static String username;
@SerializedName("email")
static String email;

public static String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public static String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

}
```

and Deserializing the JSON String (could it be a problem that it's a String?) like so:

```
           Gson gson = new Gson();
                        gson.fromJson(response, ProfileResponse.class);
                        if (Info.getUsername() == null
                                || Info.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("NO USERNAME");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("USERNAME: "
                                    + Info.getUsername());
                        }
```

This is printing "NO USERNAME" each time it's run.

Answer (score 0):

`static` fields are by default excluded from serialization/deserialization.

Remove all the `static` keywords from your classes (fields and methods), call `fromJson()` correctly, and you will then get the result you're looking for.

Gson instantiates an instance of your class(es) from your JSON. After modifying your classes, you then will do:

```
ProfileResponse pr = gson.fromJson(response, ProfileResponse.class);
```